# Copy files from subfolders into same name of subfolders at other directory

Tags: python

I need python script, which should be capable for copying files from different subfolders into new directory and this new directory should contain same subfolders. I am unable to create this sub_folders at destination during run time.
can anybody help me.

for example :
source_folder:
sub_folder1:
test1.txt
image1.jpg
sub_folder2:
test2.txt
image2.jpg
sub_folder3:
test3.txt
image3.jpg

destination_folder:
sub_folder1:
test1.txt
sub_folder1:
image1.jpg
sub_folder2:
test2.txt
sub_folder2:
image2.jpg
sub_folder3:
test3.txt
sub_folder3:
image3.jpg

Comment: Why are you unable to create the subfolders. What's the error? Can you give us the code that your using?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `os.makedirs()`  (need to `import os`) to create directory runtime. Pls. check the documentation and some examples.

Also, refer using `shutil`  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/copy-a-directory-recursively-using-python-with-examples/

Comment: @Ram if my answer has hepled you in answering your question, pls. consider marking as correct answer